# Abrir link em nova aba sem usar target="_blank" embutido no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

**Cenário**

Estou otimizando uma página onde é exibida cerca de 200 Imagens (muito pequenas não necessita paginar) de parceiros, estas imagens estão envoltas em uma tag `<a>` e todos os sites dos parceiros abrem em nova aba (`target="_blank"`).

**Obs:** Vi materiais relacionados no site porem o Javascript usado para responder a pergunta (que também não eram tão semelhantes a esta) era demasiadamente grande o que tiraria toda a economia obtida e necessitariam adaptações ao problema.

**Pergunta**

Como posso suprimir o `target="_blank"` e ainda manter as página abrindo em uma nova aba

**Código HTML**

```
<div id="minor_partners" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="link_thumb" src="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: O contexto está confuso. Acho que poderia simplificar apenas perguntando como atribuir target="_blank" para objetos <a>, sem inserir manualmente no html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maneira que encontrei foi usar uma função da biblioteca `jQuery` `.click()` para que quando a imagem fosse clicada fosse atribuido o valor `_blank` a propriedade `target`.

**Código HTML para teste**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
        Abrindo em nova Aba
    </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="minor_partners" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/"><img class="link_thumb" src="https://clubdopenguinnotice.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/edit-icon.jpg"></a>
        <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/"><img class="link_thumb" src="https://clubdopenguinnotice.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/edit-icon.jpg"></a>
        <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/"><img class="link_thumb" src="https://clubdopenguinnotice.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/edit-icon.jpg"></a>
        </div>
            <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/"><img class="link_thumb" src="https://clubdopenguinnotice.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/edit-icon.jpg"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código Javascript** (usado em elementos que não são gerados depois do carregamento da página)

```
$('#minor_partners a').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

**Código Javascript** (usado em elementos que são gerados depois do carregamento da página)

```
$('#minor_partners').on('click', 'a',function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Acho que `$('#minor_partners a').on('click',function() {` deve ser `$('#minor_partners').on('click', 'a' ,function() {` certo? para ser delegado...

Comment: Não porque o `<a>` envolve a imagem, não tive problemas da forma que esta

Comment: Mas se escreves `"usado em elementos que são gerados depois do carregamento da página"` então `$('#minor_partners a')` não os vai selecionar. Para delegares o click tens de ter `$('#minor_partners').on('click', 'elementoDelegado', etc...`

Answer (score -1):

Da pra adicionar addEventListener sem jquery sem alterar nada nas tags 'img' e 'a'

```js
const element = document.querySelectorAll('a')
element.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var url = event.target.href; // pega o href de qualquer "a" clicado
        var guia = window.open(url, '_blank'); // abre em nova guia
        console.log("Abre: " +url+ " em nova guia.");
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="minor_partners" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><img class="link_thumb" src="" title="">url 1</a><br/>
    <a href="http://bing.com" target="_blank"><img class="link_thumb" src="" title="">url 2</a><br/>
    <a href="http://duckduckgo.com" target="_blank"><img class="link_thumb" src="" title="">url 3</a><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function link(x) {
var url = x.href;
var guia = window.open(url, '_blank');
guia.focus();
console.log(url) 
}
```

e no html:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="link(this)">url 1 </a><br>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" onclick="link(this)">url 2 </a><br>
<a href="http://bing.com" onclick="link(this)">url 3 </a><br>
<a href="http://duckduckgo.com" onclick="link(this)">url 4 </a>
```

Comment: A pergunta está sendo feita justamente para evitar mudar o HTML de todas as âncoras, e sua resposta adiciona um `onclick` em cada uma delas... Se for para modificar o HTML, já adicione o `target` que é mais simples.