# como abrir link em uma nova aba?

Tags: html

Segue o código abaixo que estou tendo dificuldade de usar target="_blank"
como poderia resolver isso.

```
<div class="opt" onCLick="location.href='#';">Txt</div>
```

Muito OBRIGADO

Comment: Seu elemento é uma div e não um link, tente para `<a href="/link" target="_blank" />`

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39691/57801 , https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75901/57801 , https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39620/57801 , https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40576/57801

Answer (score 8):

Se você quer mesmo usar uma div para criar um link, segue o exemplo utilizando *Javascript*:

```
<div class="opt" onCLick="window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');">Txt</div>
```

> Substitua o 'location.href' por 'window.open', assim você consegue
>   definir o 'target'.

Se você quer fazer um link simples recomendo que utilize a tag `a`:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Txt</a>
```

Comment: Eu não queria perder o estilo que tinha aplicado na div e Você ajudou muito. 

Obrigado